# JavaFX NullPointerException when looping through TextField objects

Tags: java, javafx

So Im trying to create a sudoku solver application GUI.
I wrote out all the TextField fxid-s and created objects. And added them into an array.

So now Im trying to loop through all the TextField objects and apply .setText() it gives me NullPointerException.

```
package com.example.sudokusolver;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class Controller {

    // row 1
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x0_y8;

    //row 2
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x1_y8;

    // row 3
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x2_y8;

    // row 4
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x3_y8;

    // row 5
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x4_y8;

    // row 6
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x5_y8;

    //row 7
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x6_y8;

    // row 8
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x7_y8;

    // row 9
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y0;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y1;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y2;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y3;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y5;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y6;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y7;
    @FXML
    private TextArea x8_y8;

    private TextArea[][] board = new TextArea[][]{
            {x0_y0, x0_y1, x0_y2, x0_y3, x0_y4, x0_y5, x0_y6, x0_y7, x0_y8},
            {x1_y0, x1_y1, x1_y2, x1_y3, x1_y4, x1_y5, x1_y6, x1_y7, x1_y8},
            {x2_y0, x2_y1, x2_y2, x2_y3, x2_y4, x2_y5, x2_y6, x2_y7, x2_y8},
            {x3_y0, x3_y1, x3_y2, x3_y3, x3_y4, x3_y5, x3_y6, x3_y7, x3_y8},
            {x4_y0, x4_y1, x4_y2, x4_y3, x4_y4, x4_y5, x4_y6, x4_y7, x4_y8},
            {x5_y0, x5_y1, x5_y2, x5_y3, x5_y4, x5_y5, x5_y6, x5_y7, x5_y8},
            {x6_y0, x6_y1, x6_y2, x6_y3, x6_y4, x6_y5, x6_y6, x6_y7, x6_y8},
            {x7_y0, x7_y1, x7_y2, x7_y3, x7_y4, x7_y5, x7_y6, x7_y7, x7_y8},
            {x8_y0, x8_y1, x8_y2, x8_y3, x8_y4, x8_y5, x8_y6, x8_y7, x8_y8}
    };

    private final int GRID_SIZE = 9;



    @FXML
    protected void restartButton(ActionEvent event) {
        for (TextArea[] textAreas : board) {
            for (TextArea textArea : textAreas) {
                textArea.setText("0");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?
When applying .setText() to some specific TextField object, then it works..

Comment: The individual text areas are initialized by the FXMLLoader after the controller instance is created. So when you create the array, all the text fields are still null. You need to move the array initialization to the `initialize()` method.

Comment: This is probably a bad use case for FXML in the first place. Consider doing all this in Java instead

Comment: thanks, everything is working now!